# Trying to Simplify an Expression

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation, simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to simplify an expression:

```
Solve[En^2 - 2 (v0 + (u0 + I w0) l^-1 + (u0 - I w0) l) En +(v0 + (u0 + I w0) l^-1+(u0 - I w0) l)^2 ==
    (v1 + (u1 + I w1) l^-1 + (u1  - I w1) l)^2 + (v2 + (u2 +  
         I w2) l^-1 + (u2 - I w2) l)^2 + (v3 + (u3 + I w3) l^-1 + (u3  - I w3) l)^2, l] /. 
 {(u0^2 - u1^2 - u2^2 - u3^2) == eta[u, u],
 (w0^2 - w1^2 - w2^2 - w3^2) == eta[w, w],
 (-u0 v0 +  u1 v1 + u2 v2 +  u3 v3) == -eta[u, v]}
```

But somehow it seems like Mathematica (10) is not applying those simplifications, as can be seen in the attached picture (in red box, for one example): [image: screen shot]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please post the code once more, but as `InputForm`? Seems a bit mangled. Optimally, you would replace all subscripts and other fancy typesetting, which does not work well on this site.

Comment: I hope now it's as requested. Please let me know.

Comment: @belisarius please go and save us from fancy typesetting.

Comment: @YvesKlett done

Comment: It appears you think that (2a+2b+2c+2d)/.(a+b+c+d)->q should give you 2q. Perhaps unfortunately, Mathematica's pattern matching is far more literal than that. If you change your pattern matching to be yourResult /. (2u0^2-2u1^2-2u2^2-2u3^2)->(2eta[u, u]) and likewise your other pattens, then you do get the substitution you are looking for. More than a decade ago a paper was published on a "smarter" version of pattern matching in Mathematica which would make the substitutions you want. That was never built into Mathmatica and would probably be a huge effort to get it working today. I wish I did

Comment: @Bill why not answer?